# How can I replace an imageButton with progressBar while waiting for a request?

Tags: android, xml, mobile, android-studio

I want to replace a image button with a progressBar while a request is processed.

here is my XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_normal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="0000000000">


    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/conference_text_lockstate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_normal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_normal"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_normal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/gap_large"
        android:text="Unlocked. When all participants have joined, lock the conference by tapping the padlock."
        app:typeface="roboto_condensed_regular" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/conference_checkableimagebutton_lockstate"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/conference_checkableimagebutton_lockstate_src"
        android:cropToPadding="false"/>


    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />




</LinearLayout>
```

and I try to swap the Image button with the progressBar in the onClick Method.

```
          if (mLockCheckableImageButton.isChecked()==true){

                mLockCheckableImageButton.setClickable(false);

                ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)inflated.findViewById(R.id.pb);

                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    

         //more code here.
```

But this adds them one next to eachother. Anyone? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Relative Or Frame Layout...

Comment: if You only want to replace, then You forgott to call mLockCheckableImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This!

```
mLockCheckableImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                mLockCheckableImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    

                }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Private void showProgressBar() {
myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
myImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void showImageButton() {
myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
myImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the visibility of the `ProgressBar` to `visible`. But you don't change the visibility of the `ImageButton`. That is why they are both displayed.

First you should use a `RelativeLayout` or a `FrameLayout` so these Views can be at the same position *(with the `LinearLayout` they will be side by side)*. Then create methods to show one of these elements:

```
private void showProgressBar() {
    myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    myImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void showImageButton() {
    myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    myImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```